# Context information from a broadcastreceiver from which activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-context

Say there are two activities, A and B, and I’m currently at activity A, then some one fires an intent, which goes to the receiver has been registered to activity B (redirect to B). In this case, which context info is the receiver getting? From A or B? Thank you

Comment: it's always better to use intent extra to define which activity should use the result, as every activity who have registered broadcast receiver will notified regrading update

Answer (score 0):

It's getting the Context of the Activity that you are sending Broadcasts from.
So if you are sending broadcasts from activity A, then it will get context from A.